# Столбцы таблицы или php explode?

Tags: php, оптимизация

Здравствуйте! Что быстрее или оптимизированные, использовать:

1. Таблицу которая содержит около 30 полей, при этом в основном данные (0,1) или маленькое число;
2. Использовать таблицу, которая содержит 2 поля, но при этом во втором поле содержатся данные всех 29 полей разделенные через знак (|). А потом через `explode` их выводить как массив.

Прошу сказать только то как будет лучше со стороны производительности, по удобности написание мне как так, как так в принципе удобно. **Спасибо!**

Comment: ИМХО если всего 30 записей - то о скорости задумываться не стоит. Если только этот массив не будет прогоняться 100000 раз через цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю что производительней будет если оно будет в файле лежать, потому как в любом случае приходиться делать запрос к базе данных, но если только из этих двух вариантов то в принципе 1 лучше. Но это такой мизер что даже задумываться об этом не стоит...

Comment: Я вот тоже задумывался о файле, но вроде по скорости обработки, файл проиграет по времени в данном случае. Мизер, то мизер, но нагрузка будет давать другие скрипты на сайте, так что как говорится в народе "Копейка - рубль бережет".

Comment: Если обрабатывать немного информации то файл не должен проигрывать БД.

Comment: Файл конечно, зачем БД для таких элементарных целей. БД придумали для обработки большого кол-ва сложных данных. Соединение с БД, выборка, сортировка, вывод результата, запросы, запросы, запросы зачем? Целиком читаем файл в массив и работаем с ним! Однозначно быстрее!